# String outputs mixed of same character twice

Tags: javascript

```
var e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, str;

function capFirstLetter(str){
  return str.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() +  str.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}

e1 = prompt("Enter first name", "john");
e1 = capFirstLetter(e1);

e3 = prompt("Enter the college name you are attending to", "seneca college");
e3 = e3.split(" ");
var example2 = " ";
for(var i=0; i<e3.length; i++){
  example2 += capFirstLetter(e3[i]) + e3[i].substr(1,e3[i].length-1) + " ";
}
console.log(example2);
```

So this is what my code is. The `e3` would use the function called `capFirstLetter` and it would convert the every first letter of each word capitalized.

However, what this code would output is "*Burnhamurnham Collegeollege*".

Instead of outputting "*Burnham College*". So, its outputting extra letters of word "*urnham*" and "*ollege*", so I'm guessing it's outputting one more time without the first letter. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Remove `+ str.substr(1).toLowerCase()` or `+ e3[i].substr(1,e3[i].length-1)`

Comment: its creating extra 1 indent, so its outputting /t Burnham College, any guess to why?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

> So, its outputting extra letters of word urnham and ollege, so im guessing its outputting one more time without the first letter. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Remove `e3[i].substr(1,e3[i].length-1)` → `example2 += capFirstLetter(e3[i]) + " ";`

> its creating extra 1 indent, so its outputting /t Burnham College, any guess to why?

Remove the space in `var example2 = " ";`